# I cannot see a full list of database storage classes in Openshift webconsole

Tags: performance, couchdb, database-performance, stress-testing

I am using couchdb and I need to stress test the db to make sure about performance limitation.
I have never done any sort of performance testing. So I decided to write a piece of code to do so:

```
import couchdb

couch= couchdb.Server('xxxxxxx')

db= couch["performance_test"]

doc={
    "test": "test",
    "db":"cocuh"
}

db.save(doc)
```

So this is just a beginning and I need to add a lot to it to have it working. For example in terms of benchmarks, measure ... I am not sure what to do. Before keep going and complete the code I want to make sure I am in the right path. Is it the best way to do so? or should I use a specific tool for it? any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to figure out what you're actually measuring -- concurrent read rates, write throughput etc.

There are lots of load testing frameworks around, for example [Locust](https://locust.io/). Using an existing load testing tool gives you a lot of functionality you otherwise would ghave to implement yourself. Locust makes nice graphs etc.

There are also plenty of tools and libraries that can help you generate random test data, such as [faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) in Python.